# Where does the add(Propertyname) method come from?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm using the following lines to declare a property in my objective-c program.

```
@property (retain) int Money;
```

and the syntesize in my implementation file.

Now i wanted to make an addMoney method in my implementation to add an amount of money in my program. I was typing addMoney when i realized that Xcode was saying there is always a method with this name that i could override. It has the following signature.

```
-(void)addMoney:(NSSet *)objects;
```

and

```
-(void)addMoneyObject:(object-type *)object
```

where do they come from and who is calling them? AND how could i use it by myself? What must i attend to when using this?

Comment: What class does your class inherit from?  Bear in mind that not every auto-complete suggestion from Xcode actually gives you a legal selector.

Comment: it derives from NSObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does not actually exist. Xcode is helping you out by completing some common naming patterns. It's somewhat common to have a situation like this:

```
@class Thing;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *things;

- (void)addThings:(NSSet *)someThings;
- (void)addThing:(Thing *)aThing;
```

Xcode is just trying to make it a little easier to type that. But the methods don't really exist unless you create them.

Side note: you can't `retain` an `int`, so I assume this isn't real code. That's fine. Do make sure your properties start with a leading lowercase (`money`). It's not just individual style. ObjC relies on Key-Value Coding for many things. That requires that things be named in a certain way or it won't work.

Comment: It was from real code but i typed it in and did not copy. So i failed about the proper modifier @.@. that is easier in C#. 
Is it then possible to use -(void)addMoney:(double)value without problems? The type was wrong too :/

Comment: Sure. Though you should never use `double` for money. You want `NSDecimalNumber` or you'll get rounding errors.

Comment: Its just for the money in a game. I think i can change it anyway. i had some problems when using NSNumber but after rewriting many things i could gibe it a new try to fix my previous problems xD

Answer (score 0):

Is Money a ManagedObject (Core Data object)?  If so, that method may be being created for you.  Synthesized properties should provide setter and getter but that method would look like -(void)setMoney:(int)money  and -(int)Money

Comment: I was confused by the add method since i know that the setter and getter where named different.